# Specifying Which Kubernetes Namespaces to Display Resources from with the CLI Only

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, command-line-interface, kubectl

Is it possible to display Kubernetes (K8s) resources from multiple specified `namespaces` with ***only*** the CLI (`kubectl`)?

In other words, given two `namespaces` in a K8s cluster:

```shell
kubectl get namespaces \
--output=go-template \
--template='{{ range .items }}{{ .metadata.name }}{{ "\n" }}{{ end }}'

#=>

. . .
$SOME_NAMESPACE
. . .
$ANOTHER_NAMESPACE
. . .
```

would it be possible to `get` resources (such as `pods`) from **only** those two `namespaces` (`$SOME_NAMESPACE` and `$ANOTHER_NAMESPACE`) using ***only*** `kubectl`?

Supplying the `--all-namespaces` flag and filtering using either the `--field-selector` or `--selector` flags will **not** work, because both flags accept only `=`, `==` and `!=` operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `go-template` to print the name of the pods belonging to the two namespaces, following is an example of printing pods from the `test-1` and `test-2` namespace.

```
kubectl get pod -A -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{if or (eq .metadata.namespace "test-1") (eq .metadata.namespace "test-2") }}{{printf "%s %s\n" .metadata.namespace .metadata.name}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to use the `--output=go-template` and `--template` flags.  What if I was interested in `pods` from 10 or 20 different `namespaces` out of hundreds?  This wasn't in my original question, but would you be able to add a GoLang template that's easier to scale with to your answer?  Is there a GoLang template that does not need to check and see if a `pod`'s `namespace` is equal to any of the 10 or 20 I would be looking for?  Thank you.

Comment: I dont think, scaling it to higher number of namespace is possible without using an OR condition for each namespace.

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion that has already occurred in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52326) GitHub issue, it does **not** currently seem possible to specify multiple namespaces: either with just the `--namespace` flag alone or using a filtering flag such as `--selector`.

You *can*, for now, use workarounds such as Bash brace expansion, as suggested [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52326#issuecomment-388245064), or feeding the output of the `get` command with the `--all-namespaces` flag into `awk`:

```shell
kubectl get pods \
--all-namespaces \
| awk \
-v SOME_NAMESPACE=$SOME_NAMESPACE \
-v ANOTHER_NAMESPACE=$ANOTHER_NAMESPACE \
'$1 == SOME_NAMESPACE || $1 == ANOTHER_NAMESPACE'
```